# How do I immediately read data written to a MySQL table during the same PHP script?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I am trying to have PHP check to see if a given date exists in a field in my database and create a row with that date it if it does not exist. This part worked.

The problem is, if I try to read that row **immediately in the same script**, it finds 0 rows.

As soon as I refresh, the new row appears.

I am **not** looking for how to find the newest row; I already know how to select it.

I'm looking for how to select it **without forcing the user to refresh the page.**

I have tried `$conn->commit();` after the INSERT command. I tried "SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE". I also tried creating a while loop

```
while ($result -> num_rows === 0) { 
   $result = $conn -> query($sql); 
}
```

after the INSERT command, hoping I could force it to not repeatedly requery until the updates were committed. (This did not work).

I also tried to close and re-open the connection after running the INSERT command, but I still had to refresh before the data appeared.

```
$conn -> close;
if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

I know one option is to automatically reload the page when done, or to ask the user to refresh, but I would prefer not to do that.

---

My current code:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE date LIKE '" . $this_sunday . "%';";   
$result = $conn -> query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows === 0) {
    $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO 'table_name' (date) VALUES ('" . $this_sunday . "'); ";
    if ($conn->query($sql_insert)) {
            $result = $conn -> query($sql);
    } 
    else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql_insert . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
```

Comment: `$conn->$sql_insert` doesn't run your SQL command stored in `$sql_insert`. Maybe you want to write `$conn->query($sql_insert)`.

Comment: I was doing a multi-line query, but removed it to make it simpler. My real code is `$conn->multi_query($sql_insert)`. I couldn't remember the exact code that was right for a single query. It is now fixed.

Comment: One thing that would be interesting is if you would run a sleep for 2-3 seconds after the insert and see if it makes any difference at all. This is just to see if its a timing issue (not sure what it would be). But just to take that off the table.

Comment: **Never use `multi_query()`. You do not need it. Never.**

Comment: @MrApnea, I gave it 3 seconds. It took longer to load but didn't work.

Comment: @Dharman why not? I haven't seen anything about this.

Comment: It's a useless function, unsafe and very complicated. Whatever you need this function for, can be done in a much better and simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a primary key (which your table should have) then you can get the auto-generated ID after insertion.

But, first of all you are not inserting it properly! You should never mix PHP variables with SQL. You need to use parameter binding.

```
// Enable error reporting and connect to DB
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset

// Search for the record
$valToSearch = $this_sunday . "%";
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table_name WHERE date LIKE ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $valToSearch);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if (!$result) {
    // If no rows found then insert a new record
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table_name (`date`) VALUES (?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $this_sunday);
    $stmt->execute();
    $newId = $stmt->insert_id;
    
    // Fetch the new row by ID
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table_name WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $valToSearch);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

Of course, I would question **why do you need to immediately fetch the same data you inserted**, but if you have some trigger in the database then it might be useful.

If you can set a `UNIQUE` constraint on this column you can avoid doing this in 3 steps and do it in 2 steps.

Side note: It is easier to use PDO and it is generally better than mysqli. I would recommend to try it out. If you want to keep on using mysqli, you should wrap this in a class or function and never use mysqli methods directly to avoid all this confusion.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what is happening but i tried the following below (running from cmd.exe):

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","password","sample");

$this_name = "John";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE FirstName LIKE '" . $this_name . "%';";   
$result = $conn -> query($sql);
echo "Returned rows are: " . $result -> num_rows . "\n";

if ($result->num_rows === 0) {
    $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName) VALUES ('" . $this_name . "'); ";
    if ($conn->query($sql_insert)) {
        $result = $conn -> query($sql);
        $rows = $result -> num_rows;
        echo "Rows found after insert: " . $rows . "\n";
    } 
    else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql_insert . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}

$conn -> close();
```

And my output was:

```
Returned rows are: 0
Rows found after insert: 1
```

So for me it detected that the row did not exist, created it and make another select and found it. Could you try if the code works when not running in a webserver? Maybe copy/paste the code above and modify with your settings and see if there is any difference?

(And as others have mentioned the code contains risk for SQL Injection, but i will only answer your question for now.)